# How to make label text to grow on left while making the right side fixed in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Label text to grow on left side while making the right side fixed in vb.net.Image is attached for better understanding

Label text to grow on left side:-

[image]

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can write a good question and show us what you've tried so far. SO is not a site where you ask how to do stuff, but a site designed to help you with a speicif problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will keep your suggestion in my mind for next time. And just want to let you know that  I have solved my problem by myself, by setting the label property Flat Style to System.

Comment: If you solved your question by yourself, please answer it and mark your answer as the answer. So next time a user has the same problem he will be able to find the solution in this post

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set your text label to be **right-justified**. Showing the part of your code related to creating and populating the label (the one displaying the total amount) will help.

Comment: set the text label to be right-justified but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could set Autosize = False and choose TextAllign = *right. The actual label wouldn't grow, so you'd need to set a 'sufficient' width.

Alternative is to do it via code:

```
'find the current right alignment position
Dim rightAlign As Integer = Label1.Left + Label1.Width
'set the text (assumes AutoSize is set to True)
Label1.Text = value
'adjust position so the right hand point is in the same position as before
Label1.Left = rightAlign - Label1.Width
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your form is laid out, you can dock the label to the right and set:

```
Label.Dock = DockStyle.Right
Label.AutoSize = True
```

This will make your label expand to the left. Docking to the right will put your label at the top of the form unless you have an appropriate layout.